# Ubuntu symfony error:Could not perform XLST transformation

Tags: php, symfony1, ubuntu-12.04

I follow the symfony tutorial to build my first symfony project.
When i run:

> ./symfony propel:build-sql

I got a error:

> [propel-sql] Could not perform XLST transformation.  Make sure PHP has
>   been compiled/configured to support XSLT.

I have searched some solutions, but they did not work well.

Comment: What solutions? What hasn't worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu, I think you just need to enable the php xsl module. Try:

`sudo apt-get install php5-xsl`

and restart your webserver after. If apache

`sudo service apache2 restart`